# How to solve Induction Step in Induction Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I started with:

$E_k = E_{k-1}+\frac{k+1}{2}$

And now I'm trying to prove with induction:

$E_n = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)-6}{4}$

I started with my basis: $E_1 = \frac{(3)(2)-6}{4} = 0$

Then, assuming that $E_k = \frac{(k+2)(k+1)-6}{4}$ is true.

And this is what I have for my Inductive Step:

$E_{k+1} = E_k + \frac{(k+1)+1}{2}$

$=[\frac{(k+2)(k+1)-6}{4}]+\frac{k+2}{2}$ using our assumption from above

$=\frac{k^2+3k-4}{4}+\frac{2k+4}{4}$

$=\frac{k^2+5k}{4}$

Maybe I shouldn't have expanded the parentheses in the assumption that we inserted, but I didn't know where else to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would you like the last equation to equal? Why is that different from what you have?

Comment: I basically need it to look something like $E_{k+1} = \frac{((k+1)+2)((k+1)+1)-6}{4}$, I'm just having trouble getting it in that format.

Comment: Observe that $(k+3)(k+2)=(k+1)(k+2)+2(k+2)$.  Do you see where to use this?

Comment: And you are right it is easier to see when you don't expand the brackets.

Comment: Ah yes, I totally see where that fits in now! I didn't think about it that way, thank you for your help!!